# JavaScript object containment test similar to PostgreSQL’s jsonb `@>` operator

Tags: javascript, node.js, comparison, javascript-objects

What would be an elegant way to perform object containment check in JS/Node with similar results to PostgreSQL’s [`@>` operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/datatype-json.html#JSON-CONTAINMENT)?

For example, if such a function is named `contains()`, the following call would evaluate to `true`:

```
contains(
    { "foo": [1, 2, 3], "bar": "baz" },
    { "foo": [3, 1] })
```

Comment: just for arrays or strings as well?

Comment: Like per Postgres doc—nested object comparison with keys of any type.

Comment: There is no builtin for doing that. Can you show us your attempt at implementing it, please?

Comment: You can play with `isMatch` function from `lodash`: https://codepen.io/travist/full/jrBjBz/

Comment: @Anatoly that’s actually pretty close to PostgreSQL’s behavior, much appreciated!